# Two rivals having a mutual ally

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

**Context**

I'm playing Ottomans and Poland is my ally.  My rival is Russia, and their ally is Poland too. I'm going to declare an offensive war against Russia soon.

**Question**

Who Poland will follow in the war ? How Poland will make its decision ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The decision of whether to join a war or not is based on a number of criteria. A defensive war gives a large bonus, meaning that Poland will almost certainly join the war against you, and not with you.

I have in fact never managed to get a mutual ally to join my offensive war, so I'm afraid your plan to start that particular war is asking for trouble.

You can see up front what they will do and why. In the declare war screen you can see how high their participation as a defensive ally scores and how low joining you will score. That preview should be enough for you to reconsider.

Comment: A defensive call to arms is also automatic and immediate. It will always occur before your offensive call. As AI nations very rarely decline defensive calls, your offensive call is pretty much never considered.